# Constantly update the view angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to update the view even if the change happened from a different computer without refreshing the page.I tried to set interval and call my api every ten seconds,clear my cache.The problem here is that every ten seconds i would have to reload all my data and for the view to be update i should switch states.Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: *for the view to be update i should switch states*: no. For the view to update you should change the model, i.e. what is in the $scope of the view.

Comment: Yes you right i could just call my api every 10 sec and if my current model is different from the data i took from database update the model.

Comment: This matter is resolved then?

Comment: @MikkoViitala not yet i tried to update my model but i use $http cache so it doesnt update anything.That was what i was trying to avoid to remove my cache and load it again every 10 sec.It will slow down my whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im managed to resolve the issue.I created a function that check if the data from server is equal with the data from the model and if not i update the cache without deleting it and the model.

```
 this.refresh = function(){                                    
    apiService.someFunction(false) //the false is parametr for cache                      
       .then(function(someValue) {
           if(someValue.length !== vm.model.length){  //check if the model is equal with the data from database                                                                
              var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http')
              var get = cache.get('URL');   //getting the cache                      
              var data = angular.toJson(someValue); //turn response from then to Json
              get[1] = data; //changing the cache data                      
              vm.model= someValue; //changing the model data
           }
     })
}
```

Comment: while this probably works, it's terribly inefficient, as you are making two data calls for the exact same data.  You really should consider using a sockets library like sockets.io or similar if you want realtime communication.

Comment: @Claies yes i know.The problem is that the server already exist and its shared hosting and they dont want to leave,so i cant use node.js to instal sockets.io.If they decide to change servers i will update the app.

Comment: If you have any say to the server implementation maybe have an endpoint returning only the changed data on every subsequent call? And then angular.extend that to your existing "model".

Comment: @MikkoViitala I could do that i can use a return with every save and update  on server and return the new  data only.but the problem is that if two different computers are connected and the first change something the second should refresh the view to see that change because the model will only have been updated to the first computer.Im planing to use the function i wrote above in interval so i can  update my view every 20 sec.